# Do not allow bluetooth devices to wake computer in Monterey

Tags: bluetooth, sleep-wake, monterey

I have a pair of bluetooth earphones that are able to connect to multiple devices. For certain reasons, I would like to not connect to the computer while it is sleeping (e.g. in my backpack, on my desk while I'm in a different room and more).

This was previously possible by going into System Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced… and unchecking "allow bluetooth devices to wake this computer". However, this option apparently was removed in Monterey.

Is there a way to bring back this option despite it not appearing in the preferences pane?